# Twitter Typeahead Tags get data from MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, typeahead.js

I am trying to make a small tag-input inside a form, where I want to get data directly from MySQL.

I have found a tutorial on making a local version, where the data is stored inside an array on the page and this works just fine, but I would like it to retreive data from MySQL on the fly.

I have tried to modify the script from local to remote and I have succeeded in making connection to the MySQL database through the remote file with Json- I just cannot figure out how to make the lookup work together with the input field so that the Typeahead (autocomplete) reacts on the input.

I am not an oracle in jQuery, but I am trying to learn :-)

My code looks like this:

tags.php

```
<!-- Bootstrap styling for Typeahead -->
    <link href="/dist/css/tokenfield-typeahead.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/dist/css/bootstrap-tokenfield.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/docs-assets/css/pygments-manni.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/docs-assets/css/docs.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/bootstrap-tokenfield.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/docs-assets/js/scrollspy.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/docs-assets/js/affix.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/docs-assets/js/typeahead.bundle.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>

<p><strong>Using Twitter Typeahead</strong></p>
<form class="tagsform" method="post" action="/pages/tagscompile.php">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control tokenfield-typeahead"  name="tags" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="send" value="SEND">
    </div>
</form>

<script>
var engine = new Bloodhound({

  datumTokenizer: function(d) {
    return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value);
  },
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
        'cache': false,
        url: '/pages/tags_engine.php?q=%QUERY',
        wildcard: '%QUERY',
        filter: function (data) {
            return data;
        }
  }
});

engine.initialize();

$('.tokenfield-typeahead').tokenfield({
  typeahead: [null, { source: engine.ttAdapter() }]
});
</script>
```

My tags_engine.php file looks like this:

```
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/settings.inc.php');

$q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
if (!$q) return;

$sql = "select tags as value from tags";
$rsd = mysql_query($sql); 
while($rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsd)) {
    $rows[]=$rs;
}
// I am working on learning MySQLi but until that sticks, this MySQL will do.
print json_encode($rows);
?>
```

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works - the problem of course was in the MySQL SELECT. After making this search from the query it worked.

```
$sql = "select tags as value from tags WHERE tags LIKE '$q%'";
```

I am sorry for posting the question with such a clear mistake.